# How Can I have multiple widths and heights of subviews in a UIStackView

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistackview

Say for example I want to add 3 buttons to a stack view.

Button1 is 200 * 200  (1)

Button2 is 150 * 150  (0.75)

Button3 is 100 * 100  (0.5)

How can I accomplish this in interface builder?

Comment: set constraints on buttons and set stackview distribution as fill porportionally.

Comment: If I try to add a constraint to a subview while in a stackview I get countless conflicting constraint errors

Comment: Set constraint to your stack view first then on buttons set width and height constraints.it was working when i tried that.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can do it in the storyboard using stackview

1. Add a stackview with **Alignment Center** and **Distribution Fill**.
2. Constraints on stackview is center horizontally and center vertically.
3. Now add three buttons.
4. Constraints on button1 is height and width = 200
5. Constraints on button2 is height and width = 150
6. Constraints on button3 is height and width = 100

The set up is shown in fig:

[image]

You are having conflicts because of Alignment Property which in your case it fill. make is center and its done.

Also we can add spacing between buttons. If we set **Distribution Equal Spacing** and add height constraint to stackview with height more than height of buttons.

This is vertical stackview. You can test the same with horizontal stackview.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Works like a charm. The same technique also works for horizontal stack views containing elements which have an unequal size.

Comment: Alignment doesn't have to be centred, it can be leading or trailing, etc.

Comment: Surprisingly doesn't work for `UIView's`. I've tried the same approach for `UIView` even I've given same constraint values. Thought when I changed them to `UIButton`. It was working. Can some one suggest how to make the same to work for `UIView`. `Alignment = center` doesn't help either.

Comment: @YashBedi Change Distribution property to Fill and Alignment to Center. Time has come to move on from StackView to the new SwiftUI...

Comment: Yep got it working yesterday, before your comment ;-P. Thanks anyways...

Comment: @YashBedi... Yes... Actually Fill Proportionally does not make sense, though it was working for UIButtons...

Comment: Doesn't work for UILabels. I want to use dynamic width for label. I have 3 labels on the horizontal axis, want to set the width of left and right label to <= 0.45 multiplier of superview and fill the center label to remaining width

Comment: @hacker_1989, did you figure out how to do it with labels?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking a solution for **`UIView`**, [Here it is,](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/02/07/uistackviev-proportional-custom-uiviews/)

**UIStackView** ensures that its **arranged subviews** maintain the **same proportion** to each another as your **layout grows and shrinks**. However, unlike the other distribution options, **views that are proportional must have an** [intrinsic content size](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html).